# Insert Comma seperated values to a mysql database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I asked a similar  question yesterday but it's not the same.
I have some values that looks like this, and I want to Insert them So that

```
123,567,287,124,172,846,372,187
```

And I want it to look like this

```
id=123 and SortNumber=1
id=567 and SortNumber=2
id=287 and SortNumber=3
```

And I want to update a table based on this, so something like this

```
UPDATE char_
SET SortNumber=1
WHERE id=123
Set SortNumber=2
WHERE id=567
```

Now, I think I can do something like this

```
$variable=123,567,287,124,172,846,372,187
$anothervariable=$variable = str_replace(",", "\r\n", $variable); 


$i=0;
$i++;

 mysqli_query(UPDATE char_ SET SortNumber=$i WHERE id=$anothervariable)
```

But, I'm not sure that the code is 100 correct AND, the variable will be the whole contents and I dont know how I can set a different variable to every line?

Comment: Have a look at PHPs `explode()` function

Comment: The syntax of the `UPDATE` query you want to obtain is incorrect. You need several update statements, or a single update using `CASE WHEN`

Comment: Watch out for SQL injection; You should prefer an answer that uses placeholders or similar parameterized SQL

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, you can do this directly in MySQL

```
update char_
    set sortnumber = find_in_set(id, $variable)
    where find_in_set(id, $variable) > 0;
```

Note:  this will not take advantage of an index on `id`, so only use this if `char_` is small (tens or hundreds of rows) or you do not care about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to use `explode()` and `foreach()`.

```
$variable = '123,567,287,124,172,846,372,187';
$columns = array_filter(explode(',', $variable));
foreach($columns as $key=>$val){
    $sql = "UPDATE char_ SET SortNumber = '".($key + 1)."' WHERE id = " . $val;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    //.....
}
```